# Customizing environnment.ts depending on a value from runtime

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I have an angular application that is using two values : loginURL & logoutURL in order to ensure correct workflow of authentication in the backend.

These values can change from an environment to another.
Let's say in env X i have the loginURL set to loginURL1 and in env Y i have it set to loginURL2.

***I want to use the same artifact (dist)*** that is built and customize my env.ts file to treat both use cases depending on a variable , let's say an environment variable from the machine.
This is the content of the environment.ts file containing two use cases :

```typescript
export const environment = {


  /* Do not write your custom code here, it will be replaced by the generated content */
  // end palmyra-needle-add-environment-var
  production: false,
  userInfoURL : 'security/userinfo',
  loginURL: getLoginURL(),
  logoutURL: getLogoutURL(),
}


function getLoginURL() {
  if (**conditionMetHere**) {
    const subdomain = extractSubdomain((window as any).location.hostname);
    return `http://${subdomain}.localhost:8080/backend/login`;
  }else{
    console.log('mono')
    return "http://localhost:8080/backend/login"
  }
}

function getLogoutURL() {
  if (**conditionMetHere**) {
    const subdomain = extractSubdomain((window as any).location.hostname);
    return `http://${subdomain}.localhost:8080/backend/logout`;
  }else{
    console.log('mono')
    return "http://localhost:8080/backend/logout"
  }
}

function extractSubdomain(hostname: string) {
  const parts = hostname.split('.');
  return parts.length >= 2 ? parts[0] : '';
}
```

As you can see, the conditionisMet needs to be calculated from a variable, could be env variable but angular doesn't accept env variables as it's client side.
Is there an alternative to env variables that I could use to calculate the conditionisMet boolean ?

Comment: You could call an API that return the env config and then set it. This way you will have just one `dist` built while being dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is not possible. The environment file can't read stuff out stuff.
The environment is run client side (in the browser), so you can only access to native browser stuff.

what you can do is to read the URL or a query parameter in your `if` condition i.E. with `if(window.location.hostname === 'mywebsite1.com'){}`